# Why an initial ring is a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, soft-question

It is a well known fact that $\mathbb{Z}$, the ring of integers, is a domain. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}$ is also *the* initial object in the category Ring. If one *defines* $\mathbb{Z}$ as the initial object in Ring, is it possible to prove it is a domain without an explicit construction?

Comment: It is unclear what you would consider to be a satisfactory negative answer to this question. 
My view is that it is difficult to avoid using an explicit description of $\mathbb{Z}$, because there are many categories of rings where the initial object is not an integral domain.
(For example, the category of $k$-algebras if $k$ is not an integral domain...)

Comment: I understand that _some_ ring must be constructed. For instance, in order to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not trivial, one just need to know of a non-trivial ring, such as the power set of $\{\emptyset\}$: since there is such a ring, the zero ring cannot be initial. I wonder if something like that can be done to show that an initial ring is a domain - but without using the usual construction of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That’s an example of what you would consider a satisfactory positive answer. What would convince you the answer is (probably) no, though?

Comment: Well... I think that the lack of a positive answer works as a negative answer - until an (unlikely) positive answer appears :-)

Answer (score 7):

Let $A$ be the initial object. Let $g$ be the unique homomorphism $A\to\Bbb Z$. Consider the homomorphism $f\colon \Bbb Z\to A$ given by $$n\mapsto \underbrace{1+\cdots +1}_n$$  (Admittedly, the existence of this already somehow shows that $\Bbb Z$ is initial - the fact is simply too trivial). Then $f\circ g$ must be the unique homomorphism $A\to A$, i.e., the identity. In particular, $g$ is injective while mapping zero divisors to zero. It follows that $A$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: Why is $g$ mapping zero divisors to zero?

Comment: Any ring homomorphism maps zero divisors to zero divisors, and the only zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}$ is zero itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't see how this argument does not depend on a construction of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the argument actually shows that if $D$ is a domain with a ring homomorphism $D\to Z$, then $Z$ being initial implies $D\to Z$ has a section and hence an injective map $D\hookleftarrow Z$, whence $Z$ is also a domain.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Right, but the injective map goes the other way, from $Z$ to $D$. And it's going to be difficult to show on general grounds that there is a domain $D$ with a ring homomorphism to the initial ring.

Comment: @AlexKruckman What do you mean the other way? As I've written, it goes to $D$ from $Z$ (look closely at the arrow, it goes to the left).

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Oops! Reading on my phone, which doesn't render MathJax in comments - so I assumed the arrow was going the normal way!